# r - Library:gdata - Error parsing file, and read.xls fails to create Intermediate csv

Tags: r, excel, perl

I tried to import a xls file in to R, but it failed. It seems like the library fails to create intermediate csv file. Is any solution to this?

Thanks.

```
test <- read.xls("~/Desktop/qwe.xls", perl = '/usr/bin/perl', verbose = TRUE, sheet = 1)
Using perl at /usr/bin/perl 
Using perl at /usr/bin/perl 

Converting xls file
    "/Users/seanhuang/Desktop/qwe.xls" 
to csv  file 
    "/var/folders/ly/pxw72gmd7gjdvdbhk530cwrh0000gq/T//Rtmpx8yszv/file1491d47e6960.csv" 
... 

Executing ' '/usr/bin/perl' '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/gdata/perl/xls2csv.pl'  '/Users/seanhuang/Desktop/qwe.xls' '/var/folders/ly/pxw72gmd7gjdvdbhk530cwrh0000gq/T//Rtmpx8yszv/file1491d47e6960.csv' '1' '... 

perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_TW.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
Error parsing file '/Users/seanhuang/Desktop/qwe.xls'.

Loading '/Users/seanhuang/Desktop/qwe.xls'...
255 

Done.

Error in xls2sep(xls, sheet, verbose = verbose, ..., method = method,  : 
  Intermediate file '/var/folders/ly/pxw72gmd7gjdvdbhk530cwrh0000gq/T//Rtmpx8yszv/file1491d47e6960.csv' missing!
Error in file.exists(tfn) : invalid 'file' argument
```

Comment: This is not a code problem. You should ask whoever wrote the conversion script.